# Fitnesse Nested tables - with Column fixture

Tags: java, fitnesse

Is it possible to use Nested tables with Column Fixture?

Usecase:
I have a json which contains a Collection of objects. So I would like to assert the summary + detail-list (as a nested table). The reference i could look up was only for DoFixture. Any pointers would help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Using Java fixtures.

Comment: OK, I'm not a Fitnesse Java expert but I don't think you can use nested tables in a Column fixture.